# Where does the 404 redirection happen?

Tags: pages, redirect, 404-error, template-redirect

Can someone please tell me where the 404 redirection occurs?

I am wanting to redirect to a custom template.php instead of the 404 page.

Is this possible to do? If it is can some one provide me with a solution.

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: Why not just use the `404.php` template in your theme?

Comment: i am using one product(our application).when i call the files(pages) from that it will automatically redirect to 404.php page.but i want to redirect to another PAGE. thats why i am asking.

Comment: are you trying to redirect a tag group, post type, archive or what

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, I think I get what you're saying. However, you don't want to *redirect* on a 404, since it defeats the object of the 'Not Found' header.

However, you can filter the 404 template path and pass back your own;

```
function __custom_404( $standard_404 )
{
    if ( something_is_true() )
        return '/absolute/path/to/custom.php';
    return $standard_404;
}
add_filter( '404_template', '__custom_404' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Going off of TheDeadMedic you can try this:

Not 100% that this will work

```
function wpse_20157_404( $standard_404 ) {  
    if ( is_single() || is_tag('whatever','product' && is_404()) ) // Use || to list multiple if's
        include_wordpress_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/custom404.php');
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_20157_404' );
```

Or my original answer

```
function wpse_20157_404( $standard_404 ) {  
    if ( is_single() || is_tag('whatever','product') ) // Use || to list multiple if's
        include_wordpress_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/custom404.php');
}
add_filter( '404_template', 'wpse_20157_404' );
```

Comment: Updated answer with a second solution

Answer (score 0):

at the top of your 404.php add:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "Whatever"){
    include('another.php');
    break;
}
```

Comment: ok..but it still executed in 404.php as per your code. I want the redirection does not goto 404.php ever and it redirect to particular page.

Answer (score 0):

Since 404's happen at the server the best way to redirect a 404 away from WordPress' 404.php is by adding this to the .htaccess file at your site root.

```
  ErrorDocument 404 /relative/path/to/404page
```

This must be a relative path, not an absolute path.

Comment: although this is true you can still use wordpress for 404 errors it has that built into it.

Comment: Sure, but didn't you want to bypass the WordPress 404.php? If you don't want to use the WordPress 404.php you need to use a server 404. Anything else will send the wrong headers to the browser.

Comment: I can create a 404 page on WordPress and give it the same look as my site where as with a 404 from the server i have to grab the rendered code and add what i want to display. With the WordPress route its all dynamic. Also i am not the persona asking